# Declare inline background image in functions.php

Tags: wp-query, functions, ajax, css

I'm not sure if this can be done as I cannot find anything to help me anywhere no matter how hard i try. I'm using `Ajax` to load to in posts on the press of the button. the posts that are loaded in are formatted by my function inside my `functions.php`. That all works perfetly,the issue i'm having is the `background-image:` property needs to be `inline css` so that it can pull the image from my custom field. This all works perfectly in the template file, however. no matter what I try the `functions.php` rejects my inline style for background image no matter what I try.

Here's my If statement in it's entirety:

```
if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();


        if ($_SESSION["load_type"] == 'home')
        {
                $out .= '<div class="small-6 large-3 columns end thumb">
                            <div class="grid">
                                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                                    '.get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $size, $attr ).'
                                    <figcaption>    
                                        <h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>
                                        <hr class="light">
                                        <p class="description">'.get_the_content().'</p>
                                    </figcaption>           
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>';        
        }

        else

        if ($_SESSION["load_type"] == 'category')

        {



                $out .= '<div class="small-6 large-6 columns end thumb under">
                            <div id="case">

                                <div class="th" id="element" >
                                    <a class="fill-div" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="brief">
                                <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'">'.get_the_title().'</a>    
                                <p class="suppy">Supplier</p>
                                <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                                <a class="more-btn" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'">More</a>
                            </div>                  
                        </div>';
        }

        else

        if ($_SESSION["load_type"] == 'product')

        {               
                $out .= '<div class="small-6 large-3 columns">
                            <div class="small-6 large-12 columns end no-pad morepro" style="background-image: url(''.the_field(product_image).'')">
                                <a class="fill-div" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="product-load">'.get_the_title().'</h2>
                        </div>';

        }


    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
```

and heres the part of it that I'm having trouble with and crashes the whole site every time I try to load in a `background-image:`

```
if ($_SESSION["load_type"] == 'product')

    {               
            $out .= '<div class="small-6 large-3 columns">
                        <div class="small-6 large-12 columns end no-pad morepro" style="background-image: url(' '.the_field(product-image).' ')">
                            <a class="fill-div" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"></a>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="product-load">'.get_the_title().'</h2>
                    </div>';

    }


enter code here
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Should you be escaping those single quotes? `style="background-image: url(' '.the_field(product-image).' ')"` e.g. `style="background-image: url(\' '.the_field(product-image).'\')"`

Comment: aside from your quote issues, `the_field` echoes content, you need to use [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), which returns.